# How can I join 2 mySQL select queries that will return multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I'm currently running two queries; one to get the users a person is blocking, and the other to get the users who are blocking that person.

This is fine, but I'd like to squeeze them into one query if I can; it would be nice to not have to make another trip to the db server and hit the same table if I don't have to.

I've tried joins and unions and I'm not getting the results I want.

How can I do something like this...

```sql
SELECT
    (SELECT blocking_id FROM user_block WHERE user_id = 1) AS blocking,
    (SELECT user_id FROM user_block WHERE blocking_id = 1) AS blockers;
```

...so that I get a result that I can assign as two arrays, like this?

```php
$blocking = $result->blocking;
$blockers = $result->blockers;
```

Comment: You could UNION the two queries, or some other methods, but why are you sure it's such a bad thing to do it in two queries? What have you measured?

Comment: @BillKarwin Chasing the dragon of efficiencies, wanting to clean up my controllers, and wanting to learn. :)

Answer (score 0):

If there is a logical join condition between the two tables - we can go for a left,right or outer join. If the tables are not at all related and we just are planning to select the IDS - we can go for a UNION operation from the two different tables

```
(SELECT 'blocking' as Type, blocking_id as Id FROM user_block WHERE user_id = 1) 
UNION
(SELECT 'blocker', user_id as Id FROM user_block WHERE blocking_id = 1);
```

Post this - you can split the ids depending on the 'Type' column

Comment: Thanks. This is close, but each row is returned as a separate object when returning via JSON, which mean I have to `foreach` over them a couple times to group into separate arrays, which is what I'm trying to avoid. Tried adding GROUP BY to each sub query but that's not really giving the desired result either.

Comment: { "blocking": [2,3], "blockers": [2,4] } is basically what I'm trying to achieve through mySQL, instead of having to get messy with loops in PHP.